# Building a project with MSBuild which has only class files without a main method

Tags: asp.net

I have a project which contains only .vb files. It doesn't include a suitable main() method to detect the entry point? Can anyone suggest how to write the script for this project?

Answer (score 2):

Just build it as a class library.

If you want to see what a class library looks like in MSBuild, just create a new class library project in Visual Studio and save it. Basically, your MSBuild file should include a property like this:

```
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>
```

(If you just want to build from the command line and skipping MSBuild, use `/target:library` to tell the compiler you want to build a class library.)

Comment: could you elaborate me on using the output type tag in my target

Comment: @user533315: There should already be an output type tag in your project. Find it an change it.