# Delete a string in a file using bash script

Tags: bash, unix

We have a file which has unformatted xml content in a single line

```
<sample:text>Report</sample:text><sample:user name="11111111" guid="163g673"/><sample:user name="22222222" guid="aknen1763y82bjkj18"/><sample:user name="33333333" guid="q3k4nn5k2nk53n6"/><sample:user name="44444444" guid="34bkj3b5kjbkq"/><sample:user name="55555555" guid="k4n5k34nlk6n711kjnk5253"/><sample:user name="66666666" guid="1n4k14nknl1n4lb1"/>
```

If we find a particular string suppose "22222222", i want to remove the entire string that surrounds the matched string. In our case the entire portion around 22222222 i.e., `<sample:user name="22222222" guid="aknen1763y82bjkj18"/>` should be removed and the file has to be saved.

How can we do it? Please help

Comment: See if you've ever acknowledged users by accepting their answers for your questions. https://stackoverflow.com/users/533315/abhinav?tab=questions

Comment: @Inian: Your comment is spot on; [this one really surprised me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374225/building-a-project-with-msbuild-which-has-only-class-files-without-a-main-method), especially considering many would probably feel honored having **Jon Skeet** personally answer one of their questions.

Comment: @l'L'l Then again, it's more probable to have had him answer you than for example me. :D

Comment: @l'L'l .. I dunno. Jon Skeet didn't get a SO score of >1million just by providing high quality answers. As of this writing, Jon has posted 34140 answers to StackOverflow questions. I'm actually sometimes surprised that I come across them so infrequently ... though of course, I *never* look at Jon's highest-grossing tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `sed` utility by invoking it like this:

```
sed -i file -e 's/<[^<]*"22222222"[^>]*>//'
```